# MS SQL server - how to filter on minimum character length

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

SQL noob here, I am looking to find a way to filter on character length in a column which must have a minimum number of characters,

eg; all names returned from a column must have minimum 5 letters  (using SqL server)

I tried LIKE using [_____] , but I could not get this to work as I believe this just returns 5 letters only (not min 5?) ... any help much appreciated !

---

Tried LEN (column)>= 5 and it worked :)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried, even if it didn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious `WHERE LEN(column) >= 5`?

Comment: In case you were wondering, `LIKE` would need a wildcard `%` at the end. But obviously `LEN` is much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from MyTable
where len(MyVarCharColumn) >=5
```